# Detect if Django API query is from own-site or external client

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have Django running on a server which has a public facing API. I want to do different [django-rest-framework throttling](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/) based on where the request is coming from.
For example, if the request is coming from an Angular client on the *same domain* (e.g. my-angular-client.mydomain.com) I'd like it to be rate limited differently to, say, a curl request from someone's command line.

What is the best practice for this?

I know there is data in [HttpRequest.META](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) such as REMOTE_ADDR, but that field is empty when I use my test server rather than running locally.
There's also HTTP_REFERER, but that seems to populate only if the page is a django template page, rather than say, a client built using a different tech stack, such as Angular.

What should I be using for this use case?

Comment: A request never comes from "a domain". It comes from a client's computer. Period. The HTTP request itself contains no (reliable) information about whether it's executed by Javascript in a browser, or by some command line tool. TL;DR: you can't make this kind of differentiation.

Comment: Is there any other way to make a differentiation? The only way I can think of is to have completely different api endpoints for 'privileged' clients, but it seems like a lot of duplication.

Comment: An HTTP request is an HTTP request. You can reproduce the exact same HTTP request as the browser does in whatever command line HTTP client. Even if you add authentication or some additional "secret flags" or different URLs… they can all be discovered in the browser and replicated with a tiny bit of effort.

Comment: Are API Keys a valid option? Following the cloud.google link from the djangorestframework-api-key project, it suggests that they're applicable for identifying a client/project. I don't intend to use this for authentication of users, but the identification of a client (I want handle specific_client+anon_user scenarios). Is this still insecure in that someone could still figure out the API key out and then use it with a curl command?

Comment: API keys will be visible in the browser and can be included in an HTTP request from the command line as well…

Comment: If I'm interpreting this correctly then: API Keys are really only useful on an individual user basis, because, given that they're sending and receiving only the information they're interested in (and SSL prevents sniffing in transit), then there's really no one else to "see" into the header files. BUT, if I were to use this internally on my own client app that other people use, they could just check out the request headers and see the API-Key, and then use it themselves. I hope I've got this right. Thanks for taking the time.